# What is the adverb for describing a range from nearly perfectly to perfectly?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adverb for describing a range from nearly perfectly to perfectly?

For example:

I played basketball almost as well or even as well as a professional basketball player.

Comment: Words like ***effectively, essentially, practically, virtually, tantamount to,...*** are often used to signify *EITHER **exactly** equal to, OR **so close it makes no difference***. Informally, ***pretty much, as near as dammit,...***

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don't all of them cover the "almost" case, but explicitly exclude the absolute case?

Comment: Good Q but please show some background effort. (Not that that's easy in this case.)

Comment: @Kris: Arguably, yes. But personally, when I say ***A is effectively B*** what I often mean is *Some people might claim there's a slight difference between A and B, but **so far as I'm concerned they're the same** [at least, for the purposes of the current context]*. Maybe I should have included ***on a par with*** (or perhaps with slight rephrasing, *I play **to professional level***) - both of which muddy the distinction enough to include "slightly below" and even "slightly *above*" the caliber of an "average professional player" (or whatever *exact* level the OP has in mind).

Comment: Can I say " I played basketball pretty much or all like the professional level. Use "all" as adverb?

Comment: I played basketball as well as anyone can.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You left out **nigh**.  I play basketball nigh professionally...

Comment: @DavidM: I'd always say *I did it **nigh on** perfect[ly]*.

Comment: Your comment was nigh perfect but for that ...

Answer (score -2):

**Masterly** seems like a good fit here.

Comment: Do you mean masterfully? Please include a definition from a dictionary.